# Two double colons in the same line

Tags: php

I am trying to call a function in a class specified by a static string as follows:

```
self::$classname::myFunction();
```

PHP doesn't like the second group of double colons however. Is there any way to accomplish this without breaking it our into two lines. In PowerShell I could group the first part by using a dollar sign and parenthesis. I haven't been able to find anything similar in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For variable classes, put `${...}` around it:

```
${self::$classname}::myFunction();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/function.call-user-func.php), for example:

```
call_user_func([self::$classname, 'myFunction']);
```

P.S. Keep in mind that static methods are bad practice in OOP

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't my project. I'm just a contributor trying to keep my own contributions clean.